# Wordpress nested loop

Tags: php, nested-loops, wordpress

This is the standard HTML code I have and I'm trying to merge it into a Wordpress loop that basically displays posts in two different ways. I'm using more fields plugin for the user to choose one of two ways of displaying the post. 1) If they choose Large, the post gets wrapped with the div class 'large link' 2) If the user chooses 'Small', a div with the class 'groupOflinks' is created and the post is wrapped with a div class 'smallLink'. Only 4 'smallLink' div's/posts can be held within one 'groupOflinks' div. If there are more than 4 Small posts a new 'groupOflinks' div is created and the process is repeated.

Here is the HTML code i'm trying to merge (heavily commented):

```
<!-- Display one post within this container only & if there are more posts that have been chosen as Large, wrap them in the 'largeLink' div -->

<div class="largeLink">
    <!-- post 1 content here -->
</div>

<div class="largeLink">
    <!-- post 2 content here -->
</div>

<!-- If a post is defined as small within the admin panel (using more fields plugin) 
     display them within this 'groupoflinks' container 
     If 4 posts are already in this 'groupoflinks' container create a new container and populate with another 4 posts 
     Repeat -->

<div class="groupOfLinks">
    <!-- This is a container that holds 4 posts only & if there are more posts that have been assigned as 'Small' create a new 'groupOflinks' container and populate with the next 4 -->
    <div class="smallLink">
        <!-- Post 4 content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="smallLink">
        <!-- Post 5 content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="smallLink">
        <!-- Post 6 content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="smallLink">
        <!-- Post 7 content here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="largeLink">
    <!-- post 3 content here -->
</div>

<div class="largeLink">
    <!-- post 8 content here -->
</div>
```

This is my WP loop so far that doesn't quite work:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php // Take the value defined with the 'Layout' field and change style accordingly
$layouttype = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'layout-type', true) ?>
<?php if ($layouttype == 'Small') { ?>

<div class="groupOfLinks">

    <!--LOOP STYLE 1 GOES HERE-->
    <?php $temp_query = $wp_query;  // store it
        $args = array(
        'paged' => $paged, // paginates
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>

        <div class="smallLink">
                        <!-- Post content here -->
                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(''); ?>
                    </div>


        <?php if (isset($wp_query)) {$wp_query = $temp_query;} // restore loop
              endwhile; ?>

</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<!--LOOP STYLE 2 GOES HERE-->

<div class="largeLink">
        <!-- post 1 content here -->
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(''); ?>
    </div>


<?php } ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<div>
<div><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>

<?php else : ?>

<h2>Not Found</h2>
<p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn’t here.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting two large posts, then a group of 4 small posts, then repeat until you are done with your posts?

Comment: Any way you want it to go, I have a solution for you, just clarifying the end goal.

Comment: It doesn't matter what order they come in to be honest, though preferably in date order. Latest posts first, oldest posts last. So depending on the date they were added, I could have one 4 post container displaying first, followed by 5 (for example) large single posts followed by another small post container. Or I could have a large single post followed by 3 small post containers. I'd like it to vary in appearance depending on when each post was published. I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: But you want to include 4 small posts in every small post container?  Example: 2 large posts come first, then 2 small, then 1 large, then 2 more small-- you want this to display as 2 large, 4 small, then 1 large?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to include 4 posts in every 'groupOflinks' DIV and just the 1 post in each 'largeLink' DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a meeting in a few minutes, so for the sake of time, I'm gonna to just start you in the right direction, you may have to make a few tweaks since I wrote this in a hurry.  Let's start with your loop and make a few quick changes.

```
<?php
//Set a counter to determine if small post has been used
$small_posts = 0;
if(have_posts()) :
    while(have_posts()): the_post();
    $layouttype = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'layout-type', true);
    if($layouttype == 'Small') :
        if(($small_posts % 4) == 0) :
            $tmp_query = clone $wp_query; ?>//this line was edited
            <div class="groupOfLinks">
                <div class="smallLink">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $i = 1;
                while(have_posts() && $i <=4) : the_post(); 
                    $layouttype = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'layout-type', true);
                    if($layouttype == 'Small') : ?>
                        <div class="smallLink">
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php $i++; 
                   endif;
               endwhile; ?>
               </div>
               <?php $wp_query = clone $tmp_query;//this line was edited
        endif;//End counter check
        //Whether we needed to enter the subloop or not, the counter is incremented
        $small_posts++;
    else: //Else for if($layouttype == 'Small') ?>
        <div class="largeLink">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
   <?php endif;
   endwhile; ?>
<div>
    <div><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn’t here.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the only problem though is that it breaks my page :( Tried looking for any minor character errores etc. but can't see anything obvious...

Comment: I'll look again once I get out of my meeting

Comment: @egr103 I fixed it now.  It was missing a couple of semicolons.  I tested it and it does indeed work exactly as intended.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I have stumbled into another problem though unfortunately. It seems to work fine when there are three small posts but when adding a 4th small post (to max out that container) seems to hand the page. When it finally loads up (takes a long time) it creates a massive list of posts and duplicates them until the end of time. For reference I only have 7 posts. 4 Small 3 large :( Whats causing this problem do you think?

Comment: I'll be glad to look into it.  Give me a few moments and I'll let you know.

Comment: Adding a couple `clone` keywords solved the problem.  Look at the edit to see the new code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11712/discussion-between-austin-haskew-and-egr103)